# Way to grab what you see in Dojo Number TextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm wondering why for some widgets such as the currency widget when I perform a dojo.byId to get a value of the textbox, I get back the formatted value meaning I get back something like this: "$44.3" with the dollar sign.

However when I created a custom percent textbox, and it inherits from the NumberTextbox (as so does the currency textbox widget), for some reason doing a dojo.byId returns me the value without the % even though I see there is a % in the textbox.

I'm trying to unit test this stuff and for some reason, for the currency control I was able to  do something like this:

```
var formatedValue = dojo.byId("currencyTextBox").value;
doh.t(formatedValue === "$46.93", "incorrect formatting");
```

which when I check formattedValue it gave me "$46.93".

However when I tried this same type of deal with my percent textbox, if I see for example "55%" in the textbox, this will return 55, not "55%":

```
var formatedValue = dojo.byId("percentTextBox").value;
doh.t(formatedValue === "93%", "incorrect formatting");
```

so I don't understand why the behavior would act differently in terms of it picking up the textbox value using dojo.byId.  (Obviously if I were to do a widgetInstance.get("value"); I'd expect only a whole number to come back, the raw number without the formatting.)

Comment: Browsing the source of Dojo (1.7 I think) in a project I currently have open, it looks like `dojo/currency` bakes in locale-specific formatting. See `dojo/cldr/nls/currency` and the various `dojo/cldr/nls/<locale_language>/currency` modules. It was probably just the decision of the developers to have `dojo/currency` return its value with locale formatting, and to have `dijit/form/NumberTextBox` return just its raw number value (likely without considering the values of those modules in the same thought).

Comment: yea so the lang is changing it to text I guess which is why it's returning format, it's been changed to text by the currency.  Ok yea, I was wondering the same.